# Print emoji from Unicode literal loaded from file

Tags: json, string, go, unicode, emoji

I am attempting to print Unicode emoji characters loaded from a JSON file using Go.
When I load and unmarshal my file, the struct field passed to `fmt.Println` only prints the escaped string sequence.

For example, one string is stored within the file as `{…"Unicode":"\\U0001f47f"}` and printing it yields `\U0001f417` and not the emoji character.
Calling `fmt.Printf("%q", str)` yields `\\U0001f417`. I wasn't able to find a solution and I am bit stumped. I have attempted to remove the escape sequence and concatenate it within a template string, but it has no impact. I also attempted to use a string buffer but it didn't work either.

Comment: Stuff like `"\\U0001f417"` is _not_ a code point but a string you need to parse to finde the code point. Unfortunately the default function from the stdlib strconv.Unquote cannot be applied directly as it a) requires extra quotes and b) a lowercase `u`. So: strip anything not a number and leading zeros, parse the hex digit and format that code point with the %c verb of fmt.Printf.

Comment: Ah that's a great pro-tip. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following function to convert a rune specified in the format `\Uxxxxxxxx` to the actual rune:

```
func unquoteCodePoint(s string) (rune, error) {
    // 16 specifies hex encoding
    // 32 is size in bits of the rune type
    r, err := strconv.ParseInt(strings.TrimPrefix(s, "\\U"), 16, 32)
    return rune(r), err
}
```

A variation is to convert to a string instead of a rune:

```
func unquoteCodePoint(s string) (string, error) {
    r, err := strconv.ParseInt(strings.TrimPrefix(s, "\\U"), 16, 32)
    return string(r), err
}
```

Use the string version like this:

```
s, err := unquoteCodePoint("\\U0001f47f")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
fmt.Printf("%s\n", s) // prints
```

Comment: This is really great! Thanks for adding in the comments too; I'm always tripped up by string encoding.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this? https://play.golang.org/p/4mFQfyqeAXN

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    xx := "\\U0001f47f"

    // Hex String
    h := strings.ReplaceAll(xx, "\\U", "0x")

    // Hex to Int
    i, _ := strconv.ParseInt(h, 0, 64)

    // Unescape the string (HTML Entity -> String).
    str := html.UnescapeString(string(i))

    // Display the emoji.
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

Comment: This is a neat alternative solution! Thanks for adding it in.